# C# LINQ: 'variable 'x' of type referenced from scope '', but it is not defined'

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to implement filter by query using LINQ:

```
var ordersDetails = _repository.Get();

if (query != null)
  {
    ordersDetails = ordersDetails
      .Where(x => ordersDetails.Any(od => 
                  x.Product.Name.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(query.ToUpperInvariant()) ||                                                
                  x.Order.Customer.FirstName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(query.ToUpperInvariant()) ||                                               
                  x.Order.Customer.LastName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(query.ToUpperInvariant())));
   }
```

And I get an error: : 'variable 'x' of type 'OrderDetailsDto' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined'

Comment: What does `_repository.Get()` return?

Comment: @CodeCaster `IQueryable<OrderDetailsDto>`

Comment: Are you using EF? What's the type of _repository ?

Comment: Shouldnt this `.Where(x => ordersDetails.Any(od => x.Product.Name...` be this `.Where(x => x.Product.Name...` why `ordersDetails.Where` just to say `ordersDetails.Any` for each entry in `ordersDetail` ?

Comment: @Julien I'm using NPoco

Comment: I mean how does that method build up that query...

Comment: @CodeCaster `public IQueryProviderWithIncludes<T> Get(){return _db.Query<T>();}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but why not this?

```
ordersDetails = ordersDetails
      .Where(x => x.Product.Name.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(query.ToUpperInvariant()) ||                                                
                  x.Order.Customer.FirstName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(query.ToUpperInvariant()) ||                                               
                  x.Order.Customer.LastName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(query.ToUpperInvariant())));
```